# Playing audio via network media device

Tags: powershell, audio-streaming, sonos

I'm looking for a way to play audio using PowerShell via a network audio device.

The device is set up and I can use the right click -> cast to sonos and the audio will play fine.

I'm hoping to find a way to do this via PowerShell (i.e. to be run after something has completed on the computer).

The current code I have is below and will play the file fine via my default device. Does anyone know how to set the device to the networked speaker?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore  
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer  
$mediaPlayer.open('audio\location')  
$mediaPlayer.Play()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To get playback on a Sonos device you'll probably have to use the Sonos API: https://developer.sonos.com/reference/ .

To play a local file you'll likely need to present it to the Sonos using https or similar.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will try as you suggest and see if I get any luck. Cheers!